# Filter based on multiple criteria?

Tags: r, dplyr

Is there a way to filter based on multiple criteria for multiple levels within a column (factor)?

```
Individual<-c("a1.2", "a1.2","bd3.d","bd3.d", "k20.d","k20.d", "dfd.2","dfd.2", "d3.d","d3.d", "df3.1","df3.1")
Treat <- c('hot','hot','hot','hot','hot','hot','cold',"cold",'cold',"cold",'cold',"cold")
Time <- c("T1", "T9", "T1", "T9","T1", "T9","T1", "T9","T1", "T9","T1", "T9")
Area<- c("0.1", "0.5", "0", "0.645","0.1", "0","0.1", "0.587","0", "0.78","0.23", "0.78")
df.Area22 <- data.frame(Individual, Treat,Time,Area)
head(df.Area22, n=20)

    Individual Treat Time  Area
1        a1.2   hot   T1   0.1
2        a1.2   hot   T9   0.5
3       bd3.d   hot   T1     0
4       bd3.d   hot   T9 0.645
5       k20.d   hot   T1   0.1
6       k20.d   hot   T9     0
7       dfd.2  cold   T1   0.1
8       dfd.2  cold   T9 0.587
9        d3.d  cold   T1     0
10       d3.d  cold   T9  0.78
11      df3.1  cold   T1  0.23
12      df3.1  cold   T9  0.78
```

For example, I would just like to select individuals from the `Individual` column that have `Area` values greater than zero for both `Time` T1 and T9?

The function would therefore remove rows 3, 6, and 9.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you need selection on Area too? Bcoz there is no numerical value in Individual column.

Comment: Hi Saurabh, Sorry values of Area that are greater than zero for both T1 and T9.

Comment: according to your data, there is no any other time apart from `T1` and `T9` thus you can do `subset(df.Area22,Area>0)` if you want to include them, then you can use `subset(df.Area22,Area>0&grepl('T1|T9',Time))` or `subset(df.Area22,Area>0&Time%in%c('T1','T9'))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have to convert the Area variable into numeric as it has been interpreted by R as a factor variable.

If you use `as.numeric`, you will lose the decimal places. Hence, you have to use `as.numeric` and `levels` to ensure that the decimal places remain.

Following which, you apply the filters of T1 and T9 for the time variable and a value greater than 0 for the area variable.

```
library(dplyr)

df.Area22$Area <- as.numeric(levels(df.Area22$Area))[df.Area22$Area]

df <- df.Area22 %>%
  filter((Time == "T1" | Time == "T9") & Area > 0)
```

The end result is what you required (removal of rows 3, 6, and 9).

```
df

  Individual Treat Time  Area
1       a1.2   hot   T1 0.100
2       a1.2   hot   T9 0.500
3      bd3.d   hot   T9 0.645
4      k20.d   hot   T1 0.100
5      dfd.2  cold   T1 0.100
6      dfd.2  cold   T9 0.587
7       d3.d  cold   T9 0.780
8      df3.1  cold   T1 0.230
9      df3.1  cold   T9 0.780
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess the trick is to set `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` in the `data.frame` function.

```
library(dplyr)
Individual<-c("a1.2", "a1.2","bd3.d","bd3.d", "k20.d","k20.d", "dfd.2","dfd.2", "d3.d","d3.d", "df3.1","df3.1")
Treat <- c('hot','hot','hot','hot','hot','hot','cold',"cold",'cold',"cold",'cold',"cold")
Time <- c("T1", "T9", "T1", "T9","T1", "T9","T1", "T9","T1", "T9","T1", "T9")
Area<- c("0.1", "0.5", "0", "0.645","0.1", "0","0.1", "0.587","0", "0.78","0.23", "0.78")
df.Area22 <- data.frame(Individual, Treat,Time,Area, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
head(df.Area22, n=20)
df.Area22 %>%
  filter(Time %in% c('T1', 'T9'), 
         Area > 0)
```

In `filter` you can just add multiple filter commands with `,`, the will be treated as `&`.

Answer (score 0):

Base-R solution. As suggested by @demariod  you need to use `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` in the `data.frame` function.

```
 # Select the time T1 or T9 and Area >0
df[(df$Time=='T1' | df$Time=='T9') & df$Area>0,]
```

Output:

```
    Individual Treat Time  Area
1        a1.2   hot   T1   0.1
2        a1.2   hot   T9   0.5
4       bd3.d   hot   T9 0.645
5       k20.d   hot   T1   0.1
7       dfd.2  cold   T1   0.1
8       dfd.2  cold   T9 0.587
10       d3.d  cold   T9  0.78
11      df3.1  cold   T1  0.23
12      df3.1  cold   T9  0.78
```